# cakephp image upload error (this happends in second image only)

Tags: image, cakephp, upload

```
function package_edit($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    $this->loadModel('Package');
    $this->Package->id = $id;
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Package->read();
    } else {
        if(!empty ($this->request->data)) {
        $package_data = $this->request->data['Package'];
        $image = array();
        $formimage = array('images','images1');
        $image = array($package_data['images'],$package_data['images1']);
        $file = $this->uploadFiles('img/package', $image,$formimage);
print_r($file); /* check file upload */
        if(!isset($file['urls'])) { 
            $this->Session->setFlash(implode($file['errors']));
        } else {
            for($i=0; $i < count($file['urls']); $i++) {
        $package_data[$formimage[$i]] = $file['urls'][$formimage[$i]];
            }
        }
    }   
    if($package_data['images']['error'] == 4) {
    unset($package_data['images']);
    }
    if($package_data['images1']['error'] == 4) {
    unset($package_data['images1']);
    }
    if ($this->Package->save($package_data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your package has been updated.');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'package_list'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your package Not updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'package_list'));   
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code in this case I upload two images:

- In case I am not able to upload any image, the edit function works properly
- In case I update the first image it works properly
- Finally, if I don't update the first image, I only update the second image it shows the error

Error:

```
Array ( 
   [price] => 25 
   [no_of_peeks] => 22 
   [package_title] => gfhgfh 
   [package_desc] => gfhhgfgfh 
   [featured] => 0 
   [images] =>  
   [images1] =>  
      Array ( 
         [name] => itunes_gift_card_hack.jpg 
         [type] => image/jpeg 
         [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpBrIadh 
         [error] => 0 
         [size] => 84925 
       ) 
    )
```

please hlp?

Comment: Is it throwing error when you update both images?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $this->uploadFiles('img/package', $image,$formimage);
print_r($file);
```

In that line, looks like your uploadFiles component is expecting an array of images.
Since `$package_data['images']` is empty and `$package_data['images1']` contains the image data, you should unset the first array index of images if it's empty. The component could be terminating as soon as it gets to an array value that is empty.

It would also help if you `pr($package_data);`  before the save function and paste it in your question so we can see the data being passed to uploadFiles. Or `pr($files);` after you send to the uploadFile component.